# How to remove tr from table based on passed value from dropdownlistbox using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

Hi I am developing one application it has one drop down and grid view. I am developing this in asp.net. I decorated as drop down as multi select. As soon as user selects value in drop down i want to remove corresponding rows in grid view. The values i am getting after selecting some value in drop down and there is one hidden field in grid view. whenever both values matches i want to remove that particular row from table.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdvRegretletter" CssClass="tableform" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Vendor_ID"
        EmptyDataText="No records found !" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="gdvRegretletter_PageIndexChanging">
        <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="true" HeaderText="Select All">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" runat="server" Text="Check All" onclick="checkAll(this);" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkselect" runat="server" onclick="Check_Click(this)" Text='<%#Eval("Vendor_ID")%>' class="disablechk"/>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="id" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Vendor_ID")%>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle Width="8%" />
                <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" Width="8%" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Username") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
    </asp:GridView>
```

This is my jquery code to get value from dropdown.

```
$(function () {

        $('.limitedNumbSelect2').change(function (e) {
        var selected = '';
        selected = $(e.target).val();
        removeRow(selected);
        });
    });
```

I am not families with asp.net gridview. May i get some ideas to achieve this? Thank you all

Comment: is this  asp.net webforms?

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am using sharepoint web part...

Comment: It's been awhile that I not handle web forms and I don't remember well how thinks works using it but I think that you need to create a dropdown_selectedIndexChanged handle on codebehind, take the value of selected index, remove and update your gridview object datasource and rebind.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Even i am mvc developer. Finding hard times to work on this

Comment: Can't tell from the code as it's not there (that I can tell), but is `.limitedNumbSelect2` inside the "gridview" or outside?   asp.net gridview just generates a table: look at the html and manipulate from there, taking into consideration asp.net's terrible way of adding IDs etc.

Comment: limitedNumbSelect2 is outside gridview